# Check if CSV header exists

Tags: ruby, csv

I have class Importer for my Rails application in which I use method to import CSV file.

```
def import
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "iso-8859-1") do |row|
    mail = row["email"]||row["Email"]||row["e-mail"]||row["E-mail"]||row["mail"]||row["Mail"]
  end
end
```

I set variable `mail` to perform actions inside a loop, I try to protect it from different names of mail column, but I have no clue how should break a loop and keep a code DRY in case when there is CSV without column with any of defined headers.

EDIT:

```
def import
  header = nil
  headers = CSV.open(file.path, encoding: "iso-8859-1") { |csv| csv.first }
  headers.each { |e| header = e if e.downcase.gsub('-','')=~/^(|e)mail$/ }
  if header != nil
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "iso-8859-1") do |row|
      mail = row[header]
    end
  end
end
```

Solution to the problem

Comment: `fail 'No email in input data' unless mail`

Comment: Ok, but it will fail when single record has no email.

Comment: You claimed you want it to “should break a loop”. To simply skip a record, use `next if mail.nil?`

Comment: Maybe I have described it wrong. I would like to break loop or don't even start it if there is no column named - "email", "Email" etc.
My mail variable is just single email if it will find record in defined colums, but if there is no column it will be always nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started.  You'll need to change the regexp to match all of your cases.

```
def import
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "iso-8859-1") do |row|
    if row.headers.none?{|e| e =~ /email/i}
      raise "freak out"
    end
  end
end
```

I would also consider setting a variable `has_email_headers` that you can check since you don't want to have to scan every row's header since they are all the same.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I have observed that if you put it inside the loop it will drastically slow down importing. I have used your idea and created my own to skip implementation inside the loop. I will update my post.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [CSV documentation of Ruby 2.5.0](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/CSV.html) you can also use the `return_headers:true` to check for the `header_row?` later in a loop. Here's an example:

```
data = CSV.read("your.csv", headers: true, return_headers: true)
(0..(data.length-1)).each do |row|
   if  data[row].header_row? then
      p "yes header!"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Once could also try the `header_converters: [:downcase, :symbol]` option, to just have to check fewer values (i.e., case insensitive), such as `[:email, :mail]`:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: [:downcase, :symbol], encoding: "iso-8859-1") do |row|
  puts 'You are missing the "email" header!' unless [:email, :mail].all? { |header| row.headers.include? header }
  # refine/refactor as necessary...
  # do rest of function...
end
```

Documentation on [:header_converters](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#HeaderConverters).